# How to interface GPS device with android app

Tags: java, android, arduino, gps

I'm going to build an android application using android studio to track vehicles however I don't have depth knowledge of hardware stuff. what I knw so far is I can use the low-level programming such Arduino to configure the gps device and building the app with android studio. What I want to ask how to link Arduino program with the application. Do I need to use another high level language or any available libraries?

If there is any related tutorial about this, please provide me with the link.

Comment: Before you ask how to connect an Android app with an Arduino sketch you should first inform us how the Android device is connected to the Arduino device.

Comment: You can interface Android app and arduino using a gsm module which have internet​ connectivity (i prefer gsm 900A ) connected to the arduino.

Comment: Can you give more details i.e what you want to get from arduino to the android app..is it just latitude and longitude or any thing more

Comment: yes I just want to get latitude and longitude nothing else @Billa

Comment: to make it clear to u. i just want to view the current location of a vehicle in google map @Billa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interface Android app and arduino using a gsm module which have internet​ connectivity (I prefer gsm 900A ) connected to the arduino.

But still you cant send data directly to Android app.

So what you need to do is that you first want to save the latitude and longitude obtained from the gps to a database via GSM module .For this you can make use of PHP and it should be made in such a way that - when you request the link of that PHP code from the arduino it should store the value of latitude and longitude at that instance - to the database.
Then you could easily access this database from the Android app and do whatever you need to do with those values.This is how you can send data from arduino to Android app.

PS :

1. Buy GSM modules which support web access ( some provide only calls and message)
2. Surely you need to have net on mobile and I support web host ( not local host) for database .You can try some free hosting sites ( like 000webhost) ,if you cant afford payed hosting.

Comment: I am sure you wont understand all.Just get the module and start doing the work .If any doubt just post questions on stack and put a comment in here (so i will be notified).And the main thing is that almost same thing I did for my mini project ,so i can pretty help u.gud luck.

Comment: Happy to hear that.

Comment: sure @Billa useful answer for me thanks again

Comment: I upvoted for ur answer but it wasnt changed  @Billa

Comment: Ohh its k..thx..inform here if ur posting more questions on this.just put a link to question.